# 5 cards in sequence, don't understand answer

Tags: probability, combinatorics, poker

Find the probability that a 5 card poker hand will be 5 cards in sequence regardless of suit, consider ace high, not low.

given answer:

\begin{align}
\frac{{9 \choose 1} {4 \choose 1} ^ 5}{52 \choose 5}
\end{align}

I understand this:

${9 \choose 1}$:  9 is the number of possible 5-element sequences.

the five ${4 \choose 1}$'s are the possible suits for each of the 5 cards.

But, in the given answer i dont see how, once picked the first card of the sequence, is the player restricted to pick the remaining 4 cards so they fit in such sequence.

As far as i understand the answer, the player is able to pick the remaining 4 cards freely without having to restrict himself, or, less probably, herself, to the sequence initiated in ${9 \choose 1}{4 \choose 1}$.

An explanation of what i am missing here is greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: The numerator is the number of straights.  To count the straights, we observe that there are $9$ possible types of straights (starting with $\{2,\dots,10\}$).  Given a type, say $\{5,6,7,8,9\}$ there are $4$ possibilities for the first card, four for the second, and so on.  Hence $4^5$ ways altogether.  Thus...$9\times 4^5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both numerator and denominator count *hands*, not $5$-card sequences.

Let us count the number of *favourables*. The low *number* in our straight hand can be any of $2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10$, for a total of $9$ possibilities.

For every choice of low number, there are $4$ ways to choose the *suit* of the lowest card. For every way of choosing the suit of the lowest card, there are $4$ ways to choose the suit of the next lowest card, and so on, for a total of $9\times 4^5$.

Comment: yes, i understand that reasoning, what i dont get is how do you make sure the next card picked, "the next lowest card", actually has a rank - or face value - that is related in any way to that of the previous card. all (4 1) says is "pick some card whose suit is one of the 4 available". thanks

Comment: We are not picking cards one at a time, we are choosing an entire $5$-card hand. There are $\binom{52}{5}$ equally likely hands. Similarly, we are not picking the favourables one at a time, we are just counting how many favourables there are. One type of favourable has lowest card rank $2$, and therefore other ranks $3,4,5,6$. How many of this type are there? The $2$ can be of any of the $4$ suits, so can the $3$ independently of the $2$, and so on for a total of $4^5$ straights with low card $2$.

Comment: i see it now. You are right, what misled me was the illusion of picking cards one at a time.

Comment: Sometimes the best way to count is to imagine picking the objects one at a time. Then the denominator would have to be of the same type, that's easy, $(52)(51)(50)(49)(48)$. But counting the straights as they come is tricky.

Comment: good piece of advice. thank you

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't see it as if I was picking really. I'd just say as you did there are 9 different sequences, for those 9, there are 4 different suits for every card as you say. So that would 4x4x4x4x4 for a total of 4^5 possibilities for those 9 sequences. So 9x4^5 is the total number possibilities to fulfill your criteria.

Then (52 5) is just the total number of sequences you can get. What you need to understand is that all these cards sequences are equiprobable meaning that you have as much of a chance of getting that specific royal flush as of getting those 4 twos and a five of hearts let's say. Think about it you'll see what I mean. So with equiprobable probabilities, the probability is just the number of results that satisfy your criteria divided by the total number of possible results. Hence your answer. I'm no great teacher but I tried feel free to ask more questions :)

Comment: thanks for your comment. imagine this: 

step 1: i tell you: (9 1), you pick the lower rank, lets say it's 5.
step 2: i tell you: (4 1), you pick a suit, lets say its hearts 
step 3: i tell you: (4 1), you pick a suit, diamonds, such card could belong to any rank, let's say its 2. there our beautiful sequence, initiated with a lower rank of 5 is broken. Nothing forbade you from picking a 2. You complied with the only restriction imposed (choosing one out of four suits). That' is what puzzles me. Thanks.