# 7 cards in sequence (suit does not matter)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games, poker

Problem: Pick 7 cards from the regular 52 English cards deck, were they must be in order and suits don't matter (aces can loop).

As stated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1697787/5-cards-in-sequence-dont-understand-answer) for this similar problem, I suppose the answer would be something like:

$\frac{\binom{13}{1}\cdot\binom{4}{1}^7}{\binom{52}{7}}$

And I understand the reason for the top part of that fraction, where the $\binom{13}{1}$ corresponds to every one card I pick, times 1 suit out of 4 in total; 7 times (for each card).

The thing is that I don't quite get why I need to divide this number by $\binom{52}{7}$ and what it means for the problem.

Thanks for any help, sorry for my English.

Comment: If you are interested in calculating a probability, the sample space consists of all seven card hands that could be drawn from a deck with $52$ cards.  The number of such hands is $\binom{52}{7}$.

Comment: The ${13 \choose 1}$ actually stands for the _starting rank_ in your sequence.  There are 13 choices and once you pick the lowest rank the sequence must be $i, i+1, i+2, ... i+6$ (loop around if necessary).  Then for each rank you have 4 choices.

Comment: Define sequence and loop.  If you are asking about the standard definition of a straight then this is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Appears you are not using standard definition of a straight.

If you allow loop on ace the there are 13 unique straights.   $\binom{13}{1}$
Of the 7 cards they can be any suit.  ${\binom{4}{1}^7}$

${\binom{52}{7}}$ is simply the number of 7 card hands taken from 52 cards